# How to find AD entry without raising an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, windows-server-2008, user-accounts

I have the following code that removes a local user account from the AD:

```
try
{
    string username = "MyUserName";

    using (DirectoryEntry hostMachineDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://localhost"))
    {
        DirectoryEntries entries = hostMachineDirectory.Children;

        DirectoryEntry deUser = null;
        try
        {
            deUser = entries.Find(username, "User");
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            //Look for "no such user" exception
            if ((uint)ex.ErrorCode != 0x800708ad)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        if (deUser != null)
            entries.Remove(deUser);
        else
            ShowMessageBoxError("No such user: " + username, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ShowMessageBoxError(ex);
}
```

Is there any way to avoid raising and catching that exception in case there's no such user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up context to your local machine only
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    // find your user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);

    if(user != null)
    {
       // if user is found - remove it
       user.Delete();
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Answer (score 0):

You could use DirectorySearcher instead. 
Set a filter, call FindOne method and then check if result is null